# R: Unlist list to columns in dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr

I have a data frame which is made of up:

```
Var1  Var2   Var3
a      b     nested list
```

Nested list =

```
 ####test:
           apple: a
           pear:   b
  ####test2:
             apple: a
             orange: c
```

Is there a simple way to turn the nested list in v3 of each row into further columns, with the list element names as the variable names and each list value in each cell? 
e.g.

```
Var1 Var2 Var3        apple pear orange
a    b    nested list   a   b    NULL
```

Comment: Please make the data in your question reproducible. Simulate an object, what the end result should look like and your current attempts which work or not.

Comment: Not sure how you do that in the app?

Comment: e.g var1 a var2 b var3 (nested listed list)

Comment: Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for `tidyr::spread()`. It is anyways hard to try other things without a reproducible example.